# Getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines' when trying to call method

Tags: python, text

So, I am trying to read only one line from a text file that I opened, but I keep getting this error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'`.

Here is the code.
I am not very comfortable in python.
What should I do?

```
file = askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Text File", ".txt"), ("All Files", ".")),
                       title = "Please, choose a file") 
if file is None:
    return

content = file.readlines()
print(content[74])
```

Comment: But, surely `askopenfilename()` only returns a filename. Did you mean `content = open(file).readlines()`?

Comment: The attribute error means that `readline()` is not a string method which is because `file` is a string, not an open file.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`askopenfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile) instead.

```
file = askopenfile(filetypes = (("Text File", ".txt"), ("All Files", ".")), title="Please, choose a file", mode="r")
if file is None:
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that 'file' is just the path to the file, so you actually have to do like fileContent = open(file) and then fileContent.readlines(). I may be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
filename = askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Text File", ".txt"), ("All Files", ".")),title = "Please, choose a file") 
filename
f=open(filename)
f.read()
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx for the answers, my question wasnt very clear sorry.

I made a button that allows to import a txt file. After reading this txt file I just want to retrieve a particular line

heres the few code i wrote.

````
        file = askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Text File", ".txt"), ("All Files", ".")),title = "Please, choose a file") 
      
        if file is None:
                return

        with open(file, 'r') as f_in:
                text = f_in.read()
    
        ```
````